# Can LOAD DATA INFILE accept regex for LINES STARTING BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, load-data-infile

My file format:

```
-----------------------------------
|  CCAr|Next date |Cred. acct|
|---------------------------------|
|  1143|08/01/2019|123456789| 
-----------------------------------
```

What I want to load into `MariaDB 10.3` is only line with data which is line starting with 1143

Is there a way, MariaDB can load just lines starting with `REGEXP '^\\|\\s*[[:digit:]]'` ?

I tried using `LINES STARTING BY REGEXP '^\\|\\s*[[:digit:]]'`, but I get following error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn:833) You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP '^\|\s*[[:digit:]]'

P.S.: Please note that I can not use `IGNORE x LINES` here because my file has got repeated header lines which I am not showing here for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to apply a regex or where filter during the `LOAD DATA` command.  But, you may proceed to read in all rows initially, and then use a delete statement afterwards:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT CCAr LIKE '1143%';
```

Answer (score 0):

On a *nix, clense the file first:

```
egrep '^1143'  < in.txt  > out.txt

LOAD DATA INFILE ... "out.txt" ...
```